# An example of morphism not of finite type

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is example 3.2.2 of Chapter II of Hartshorne's algebraic geometry. If P is a point of a variety V, with local ring $O_P$, then $Spec O_P$ in general of finite type. I did not see an example right now. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried...any examples?  It's arguably harder to find an example where it _is_ of finite type.

Comment: For instance, have you tried $V=\mathbb{A}^1$?

Comment: @EricWofsey For affine line, say, if you take the generic point, then you get $k(x)$, but this should be a finitely generated $k-$algebra, as it is generated by $x$ and $x^{-1}$, am I right? or I made some mistakes?

Comment: $k(x)$ is not generated by $x$ and $x^{-1}$: for instance, it also has elements like $(x+1)^{-1}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Aha, I see it. I just took a very good point. If I take $(x)$, then $k[x]_{(x)}$ is not finitely generated $k-algebra$ as we need generators like $x-m$.

Comment: @EricWofsey You are right, I made a huge mistake. Thank you.